# downsampling does not appear on the main frame

Tags: html, css

In html I use the frame on the main page but the downsampling does not appear on the main frame  please solve the problem

```html
<pre>  
    <frameset rows = "15%,90%" frameborder="YES" border="2" framespacing="0">
        <frame src="html/top_frame.html" name="top">
        <frame src="html/login.html" name="main" scrolling="YES" >
    </frameset>
</pre>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  
         <pre>
              <frameset rows = "15%,90%" frameborder="YES" border="2" framespacing="0">
              <frame src="html/top_frame.html" name="top">
              <frame src="html/login.html" name="main" scrolling="YES" >
              </frameset>
       </pre>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [The `frameset` element is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) in most situations it is unneeded. It definitely won't work when surrounded by `pre` tags, as that causes the code between them to be interpreted as text.

Comment: Also, what "downsampling" are you referring to?